# Chrome for Android - Notifications don't appear

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications

I have a problem with Chrome for Android both standard and dev (51). While notifications api works perfectly on other browsers (Chrome & Firefox on desktop + Firefox on Android), it fails unfortunately on mobile chrome. The browser asks for a permission on notification event, but it doesn't display it. As mentioned above Firefox on the same phone has no problem with that, as well as desktop version of Chrome. Here's my code:

```
handleNotification: function (message) {
    if (!Notification) { return; }
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted") { Notification.requestPermission(); }
    else {
        var notification = new Notification(participantsRepository[message.senderID].firstName, {
            icon: participantsRepository[message.senderID].photo,
            body: message.body,
        });
        notification.onclick = function () {
            this.props.updateViewOnMessengerComponent('threadView');
            this.updateCurrentThread(message.thread, true);
        }.bind(this);
    }
},
```

Any ideas how to fix it?
Cheers, Wojtek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked Alex Russel about this issue on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/wojtekkulma/status/721036006368100352) and  it turned out that legacy notification API, which I'm using in my app isn't currently supported in any mobile version of chrome. Looks like I have to use Google's official push notifications API especially for android users.

Comment: can you please provide more details ? what do you mean by `Google's official push notifications API` ?